# How to distribute logging config with Python package

Tags: python, logging

Adding config file to package is not a big deal. But when I upload package to pypi and install it, it's not possible to read logging config:

```
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
```

basically my modules don't find it because file is not in *current working directory* anymore. How can I address that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `logging.conf` exists in the same directory as the file calling `logging.config.fileConfig`, then you could use:

```
import os
logconf_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'logging.conf')
logging.config.fileConfig(logconf_file)
```